# Google Sheets - Send email/slack for selected sheets only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a working script that sends an email when a certain column gets updated but the workbook I'm in has loads of sheets so I'm looking for a way to send email changes only on certain named sheets - e.g. "System 1", "Database 2", "Database 2".

Thanks

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var column = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  var colLetter = columnToLetter(column);
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var name = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).getValue();
  var recipients = "email.com";
  var message = '';
  if(cell.indexOf('N')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('F'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var subject = 'Update to  ' + sheet.getName() + '';
  var body = ' Hello, An update has been made to the system for ' + sheet.getName() +   ' now updated ' + cellvalue + '  ' + name + '  , Thanks'  ;

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
function columnToLetter(column) {
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0)
  {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}

function letterToColumn(letter)
{
  var column = 0, length = letter.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    column += (letter.charCodeAt(i) - 64) * Math.pow(26, length - i - 1);
  }
  return column;
};

function onEdit(e)
{
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();

  if(column == 14)
  {
   // call your send notification function
   sendNotification();
  }
}

function sendToSlack() {
  var timestamp = new Date();

  // custom slack webhook
  // change the XXXXX's to your own slack webhook. Get it from: 
  // https://my.slack.com/services/new/incoming-webhook/
  var url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

  var payload = {
    "channel": "@testing",
    "username": "System",
    "text": "Hello, An update has been made to the  system for " + sheet.getName() +   " now updating " + cellvalue + "   , Thanks  ",
    "icon_emoji": ":inbox_tray:"
  };

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var shts=["System 1", "Database 2", "Database 2"];
  if(e.range.columnStart==14 && shts.indexOf(e.range.getSheet().getName())>-1) {
   sendNotification();
  }else{
    return;
  }
}
```